# How to assign Values to a Property of an object using Task in C#

Tags: c#, reference, task-parallel-library, multitasking, ref

I'm Having a Model Class, each property is mapped with a Model Class.

Consider the Model Class "**`Contact`**"

```
public class Contact
{
    public Profile profileInfo { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Task related C# Code is

```
public void MapContact(ref Contact contactInfo)    
{
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        contactInfo.profileInfo = client.GetProfileInfo(1);
    }));

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
```

I'm getting the Compile Time error "*Cannot use ref or out parameter 'contactInfo' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression*" in the following statement

```
contactInfo.profileInfo = client.GetProfileInfo(1);
```

Kindly assist me how to use Task efficiently without any Compile-Time Error.

Here with I attached the Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What's the signature of `client.GetProfileInfo`?

Comment: @lukegv - Profile

Comment: @lukegv - The Error is not related to the signature of client.GetProfileInfo

Comment: The code in the question does not produce the error described, please post a [mcve].

Comment: you could remove ref from your method signature, classes are always reference parameters

Comment: @MaksimSimkin - I need the `ref` keyword to keep the original reference, kindly assist me how to overcome the issue in this scenario, kindly don't suggest to avoid the `ref`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - In my real implementation I'm doing most of the assignment to the actual reference, some scenario I'm assigning the Empty Instance (i.e., new Contact()) so in this case I need the actual reference without `ref`, I can't. So, please provide some solution based on my requirement.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Thanks for your kind attention. I think you are not aware of this, some one will answer for this question.. Once again Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare a local variable of same type Contact and just pass this local variable to that Task

C# Code:

```
public void MapContact(ref Contact contactInfo)
{
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    Contact pro = contactInfo;

    taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        { pro.profileInfo = new Profile() 
            { 
                FirstName = "Stack", 
                LastName = "Overflow" 
            }; 
        }));

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
```

The LinqPad Output is
[image]

Comment: @HenkHolterman - We are here to give only the solution or suggestion that's our limit. If we are trying to influence the questioners, its not a healthy discussion. Because no one should post the actual code, most of us depicted the actual scenario with sample codes. We don't know the actual purpose of `ref`, So in this scenario don't try to break the questionnaires requirement, If you did no one should come forward to post the question. It's my humble request...

Comment: When the `ref` is not necessary, then your answer isn't needed. When it is essential, then your answer won't be enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Stupid guidelines. First read the guidelines thoroughly. The Guideliness are framed for us, that's only for streamline the discussion not for suicide. If any one asking the question, they are posting to get some solution, but people like you thinking we are the superior we are the admins as like that. That's the only problem for the new comer's.  First change the attitude.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - He is expecting the `ref`, what's the lacking factor in my answer. just point out or just post your answer.